# c++ How to call yourself in singleton construction

Tags: c++, singleton

```
#include <iostream>

class demo1
{
public:
    demo1();
};

class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton();
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance();
};

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
{
    static Singleton s;
    return &s;
}

Singleton::Singleton() 
{
    demo1 d1;
}

demo1::demo1()
{
    Singleton::getInstance();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "vs2017 begin" << std::endl;
    Singleton::getInstance();
    std::cout << "vs2017 end" << std::endl;
}
```

visual studio 2017 not responding
But can run in visual studio 2005

This project is a problem that arises when VS2005 is upgraded to vs2017. I'm curious why it can be done in VS2005

[visual studio 2005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JXQg.png)
[visual studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPHDU.png)

Comment: _Why_ do you want to call `getInstance` in the constructor?

Comment: If the constructor needs to refer to the Singleton instance during construction, you can just use `this`. By the definition of a Singleton, it must be the singleton instance that is being constructed.

Comment: This project is a problem that arises when VS2005 is upgraded to vs2017. I'm curious why it can be done in VS2005

Comment: It can be done "by accident". This should never be done. The first time you enter `getInstance`, a lock is taken, the second time you enter you block on the lock. Or not, as seen in VS2005, but thats pure accident.

Comment: It will be 100% implemented in VS2005, which makes me very confused

Comment: Recursively passing the declaration while construction of the object is in progress in the same thread causes undefined behavior, see https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#3. If it worked beforehand it was just luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialization recursion since your `getInstance()` function uses the constructor to create an object which then calls `getInstance()`.

> Dynamic initialization of a block variable with `static` storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. [...] If control re-enters the declaration recursively **while the variable is being initialized**, [the behavior is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

*"Working in VS2005"* is one possible outcome of *undefined behavior*.

In this case, your constructor doesn't need to do anything and then everything will be ok:

```
Singleton::Singleton() = default;
```

---

Out of scope of the question: I suggest that you return the instance by reference instead. It makes integrating with most other code easier:

```
Singleton& Singleton::getInstance()
{
    static Singleton s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `You have infinite recursion` Actually, you don't, "Meyers Singletons" are initialized exactly once, the Standard guarantees this. The second entry to `getInstance` is probably UB either way as the lock is already held by the current thread, I'm not sure whether the Standard says anything about reentry of such functions containing a Meyers Singleton,

Comment: It will be 100% implemented in VS2005, which makes me very confused

Comment: I reworded it a bit - being a bit more careful about "infinite" etc.

Comment: @ClearSeve Visual Studio 2005 is too old to give multithreaded protection, so you're probably getting recursion. If you have the opportunity, you should consider upgrading from the compiler equivalent of a bronze-tipped spear.